# JSP Scriplet Chinese String comparison

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying the following JSP code on server

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-16"
    pageEncoding="UTF-16"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-16">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

String s = "繁體中文";

String s1 = "繁體中文";
out.println(s + "<br/>");
out.println(s1 + "<br/>");
out.println(s.equalsIgnoreCase(s1 + "<br/>"));
%>

</body>
</html>
```

and when I see the output, it gives me false for comparison.

Could anyone please look into this and guide me whats wrong.

Note: I have tried UTF-8 encoding as well.

Thanks.

Comment: You placed `)` to late. Move one before `+ "<br/>"`.

Comment: Thanks Pshemo for pointing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cause you comparing "繁體中文" with "繁體中文[br]"

```
s.equalsIgnoreCase(s1)
```

will give you true

Answer (score 2):

You may need to change condition as follows.

```
out.println(s.equalsIgnoreCase(s1));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ritesh: You are comparing s with s1+"[br]" while you should compare s with s1 only.
So use the following code:

```
out.println(s.equalsIgnoreCase(s1));
```